# In IOS 7.0.3 Safari, JQuery Mobile popup with overlay doesn't fill window

Tags: jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and JQuery 1.10.2, and have the following issue:

When you scroll down in mobile safari on IOS v7.0.3 and the address bar shrinks and the bottom bar disappears, the JQuery mobile overlay no longer fills the entire viewport.  I've tried several things such as manually increasing the height using JQuery when my popup menu displays.

```
$('#popupMenu').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var device = navigator.userAgent,
        height = $(window).height();
    if(device.match(/(iPhone)/) {
        $('#popupMenu').css('height', height);
        $('.ui-overlay-a').css('height', height)
    }
    $('#menu').popup('open');
});
```

The overlay will briefly show at 460px and then resize back to about 100px from the bottom of the screen, and the menu will display at a height minus the bottom bar height.

Is this a known issue with JQuery Mobile 1.3.2?  What can I do to fix without going to JQuery Mobile version 1.4.0?

Thanks.

Comment: `#popupMenu` is a popup right? you're adding a `click` listener on the popup itself to open the same popup?

Comment: That's a mistake in my code.  The popup menu should open the menu popup.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: I'll work on one in a little while.  But I don't have one ready to go yet.